# Check whether a folder is a local or a network resource in .NET

Tags: networking, directory, .net

Is there a quick way to check whether a path I have is on a local disk or somewhere on the network? I can't just check to see if it's a drive letter vs. UNC, because that would incorrectly identify mapped drives as local. I assumed it would be a boolean in the DirectoryInfo object, but it appears that it's not.

I've found classic VB code to do this check (through an API), but nothing for .NET so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo di;
                if (System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(di.FullName))
                {
                    System.IO.DriveInfo drive = new System.IO.DriveInfo(System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(di.FullName));
                    if (drive.DriveType == System.IO.DriveType.Network)
                    {
                        // do something
                    }
                }
                else // shouldn't be reached
                {
                    // relative path => local
                }
```

Comment: Noce, but the "if (Path.IsPathRooted(di.FullName))" seems quite unnecessary in general, since the very use of FullName is returning a rooted path.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the UNC-check. Then, if it is not a UNC path, create a `DriveInfo` object for the drive and check the `DriveType`.

Answer (score 0):

From the drive letter in the path, get a DriveInfo instance. This has a DriveType property, which can be:  CDRom, Fixed, Unknown, Network, NoRootDirectory, Ram, Removable, or Unknown