# How to check if path refers to a local file object?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

I'm trying to find out if some arbitrary path refers to a local file system object vs. the one located on a network share or a removable drive. Is there any way to do this in .NET?

PS. In other words, if I have hard drives C: and D: and drive E: is a DVD drive or a USB flash drive, then:

The following paths will be local:

```
C:\Windows
D:\My Files\File.exe
```

And the following paths will be not:

```
E:\File on usb stick.txt
\\computer\file.ext
```

Comment: The DriveInfo class will tell you the type of drive it is from the drive letter.

Comment: This question appears to have already been answered in [this thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455348/check-whether-a-folder-is-a-local-or-a-network-resource-in-net

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace random
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

           //TEST HERE
            bool isFixed = allDrives.First(x=>x.Name == "D").DriveType == DriveType.Fixed

            foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("  File type: {0}", d.DriveType);
                if (d.IsReady == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
                    Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "  Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes",
                        d.AvailableFreeSpace);

                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "  Total available space:          {0, 15} bytes",
                        d.TotalFreeSpace);

                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "  Total size of drive:            {0, 15} bytes ",
                        d.TotalSize);

                }
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You want the DriveInfo class, specifically [DriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.drivetype.aspx) - the enumeration description:

> The DriveType property indicates whether a drive is any of: CDRom,
>   Fixed, Unknown, Network, NoRootDirectory, Ram, Removable, or Unknown.

Comment: OK, that is close to being testable. You forgot to mention how to initialize `DriveInfo` constructor with a drive letter from a path. This stuff: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.driveinfo.aspx

Comment: @ahmd0 I am using a static method of DriveInfo - no constructor required

Comment: @ahmd0 just use do a allDrives.First(x=>x.Name == "D").DriveType == DriveType.Fixed having extracted the drive letter from the path to test

Comment: @Jacee: I just tried it as such: `DriveInfo di = new DriveInfo(@"D:\My Files\File.exe");` and it worked. Am I using something undocumented?

Comment: @ahmd0 No, the DriveInfo constructor accepts a path, so you could load the info that way for a specific path